# how can i display all items randomly in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to split a word into letters put it into in array and display the letters randomly. i am having trouble. with words that have double of the same letter. and also the correct amount of letter is being shown but not all the letters are being displayed.

Here is my code I'm a noob:

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  //var name=prompt("what is your name ? ","");
  //character(name) ;
  words();
}

function character(name) {
  var name = name;
  document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = "hey " + name + " my name is koala could you help me put these words back in order?";
}

function words() {
  var lastlet = "";
  var words = ["joe", "suzy", "terry", "fox", "lopez"];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length) + 0;
  //for one word and seperation with letters
  var ranwor = words[rand].split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < ranwor.length; i++) {
    var inn = ranwor[Math.floor(Math.random() * ranwor.length)].split().shift();
    if (true) {
      var di = document.getElementById("wor").innerHTML += inn;
    }
    lastlet = inn;
  }
}
```

```css
#char {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
}

#words {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="char" src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg" />
<p id="words"></p>
<br>
<p id="wor"></p>
<p id="wo"></p>
<br>
<textarea id="inp"></textarea>
<br>
<button>
  I think this is right :)
</button>
```

Comment: You are choosing random letters from "ranwor" without saying they cannot be chosen more than once. So it looks for a random letter per each letter in a word. Nothing stops it from choosing "j" three times when "joe" is chosen.

Comment: @Valdorous so what am i suppose to do ?

Comment: `"applesauce".split("").sort(function(){ return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1; }).join("")`

Comment: @epascarello that did not work

Comment: @benji8 really? I just made an answer below and seems to work for me. Plus random can also mean the same word pops out. :)

Comment: what if i do not want the same word to pop up. like i want to repeat the loop until all word are displayed. @epascarello

Comment: Did you look at my answer below???

Comment: @epascarello yeah but the console.log .. is not displaying things where i want

Comment: What does it not do correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the array using a random number and use join() so you do not need to loop.

```js
var words = ["joe", "suzy", "terry", "fox", "lopez"];
var rand = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];


function scramble (word, rescrambled) {
    var scrambled = word.split("").sort(function(){ return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1; }).join("");
    if (word===scrambled  && !rescrambled) {  //if it matches the original, retry once
        return scramble (word, true);
    }  
    return scrambled;
}

console.log("Random word: ", scramble(rand));

console.group("loop them");
while(words.length){
   var x = words.pop();
   console.log(x,":", scramble(x));
}
console.groupEnd("loop them");
```